# How to generate OAuth signature with c# for Twitter API 1.1?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm working on an app and a part of it is to get the mentions count of this app. I created an app on Twitter and I generated an OAuth signature for the REST API v1.1 GET statuses/mentions_timeline and access the mentions timeline to get the count (https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json). My question is how did we dynamically generate the oauth signature to access the mentions timeline and get the counts.

Comment: Old question but please see my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/

Answer (score 1):

You can either write your own OAuth provider or use an existing library.  Here's a list of 3rd party libraries on the Twitter site:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet

DotNetOpenAuth is good and there are others.

If you want to write your own, check out Twitter's OAuth documentation:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth

and here's another good OAuth reference:

http://hueniverse.com/oauth/

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth implementation does not change with the new (controversial) Twitter API. You can keep on generating OAuth signatures just like you did with Twitter API 1.0.