# Authenticate and request a user's timeline with Twitter API 1.1 oAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, webclient, twitter-oauth

This morning I have received the dreaded 'The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1.' error in a few of my web sites.

Previously I have been using javascript/json to make these calls to http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json? to display a timeline.

As this is no longer available I need to adopt the new 1.1 API process.

I need to do the following using HttpWebRequest objects not a 3rd party application:

1. Authenticate using oauth key and secret
2. Make an authenticated call to pull back to display users timeline

Comment: A mixture, I have traditional and mvc.

Comment: Have you seen **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479575/how-to-generate-oauth-signature-with-c-sharp-for-twitter-api-1-1)**? There's also a list of third party libraries on the twitter dev site - there are a few C# ones.

Comment: @Jimbo Hi, yes thanks. I need to avoid 3rd party libraries. The reason being that I need to use it in many different type of applications (mvc and traditional apps), CMS, portals etc. I've almost done it, I'll post the answer if it works.

Comment: @hutchonoid Is it possible to do a keyword search for all user in a WebForm ???

Comment: @PhillHealey Yes, I believe you can. Basically anything that is available from the twitter api can be exposed although you may have to extend/modify the source on github.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Here is what I did to get this working in a simple example.

I had to generate an oAuth consumer key and secret from Twitter at:

https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

I deserialized the authentication object first to get the token and type back in order to authenticate the timeline call.

The timeline call simply reads the json as that is all I need to do, you may want to deserialize it yourself into an object.

I have created a project for this at : https://github.com/andyhutch77/oAuthTwitterWrapper

**Update** - I have updated the github project to include both asp .net web app & mvc app example demos and nuget install.

```
// You need to set your own keys and screen name
var oAuthConsumerKey = "superSecretKey";
var oAuthConsumerSecret = "superSecretSecret";
var oAuthUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
var screenname = "aScreenName";

// Do the Authenticate
var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

var authHeader = string.Format(authHeaderFormat,
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey) + ":" +
    Uri.EscapeDataString((oAuthConsumerSecret)))
));

var postBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";

HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);
authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
authRequest.Method = "POST";
authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

using (Stream stream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
    stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
}

authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

WebResponse authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
// deserialize into an object
TwitAuthenticateResponse twitAuthResponse;
using (authResponse)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(authResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var objectText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        twitAuthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitAuthenticateResponse>(objectText);
    }
}

// Do the timeline
var timelineFormat = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={0}&include_rts=1&exclude_replies=1&count=5";
var timelineUrl = string.Format(timelineFormat, screenname);
HttpWebRequest timeLineRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(timelineUrl);
var timelineHeaderFormat = "{0} {1}";
timeLineRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format(timelineHeaderFormat, twitAuthResponse.token_type, twitAuthResponse.access_token));
timeLineRequest.Method = "Get";
WebResponse timeLineResponse = timeLineRequest.GetResponse();
var timeLineJson = string.Empty;
using (timeLineResponse)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(timeLineResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
         timeLineJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}


public class TwitAuthenticateResponse {
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should shove this into a class and put it on github for others to use ;)

Comment: Thanks a million for sharing this - it really helped me get back up and running quickly! One suggestion with your solution would be to allow parameters to be passed into the OAuthTwitterWrapper object either through the constructor, or by making the properties public. In my case, I wanted to be able to vary the number of tweets to show depending on the real estate available on the page. All the same, a nice solution and thanks!

Comment: No problem, it's good to see it being used. I will add those changes to the project that you suggest. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you find any bugs.:)

Comment: Awesome post, this should be on Twitter docs page, far easier to understand!

Comment: @timothyclifford thanks, I must admit I struggled with the twitter docs too.

Comment: @hutchonoid would it be possible to get this as a dll for .net 2.0? i downloaded the solution from github, but don't see a dll and don't know how to make that code into a dll. Thanks!

Comment: @kylemac you should be able to get the dll by creating a project and adding it via nuget. Te URL is on GitHub, or just download it outside of a project & rename the package to a zip. It will be in there.

Comment: thanks @hutchonoid. I was able to get the dll, but it is .net 4 and the project i'm updating is in .net 2.0... is it possible to put this in 2.o? (I see the newtonsoft comes in multiple versions.)

Comment: @kylemac No problem, sorry but I don't have a dev environment setup to release a .net 2.0 version. You could fork my project and create a one. I'm sure it won't be too difficult.

Comment: You've saved me a lot of hassle here mate!

Comment: @DeeMac Good to hear, I was amazed I couldn't find anything online at the time.

Comment: Well I've been trying for a while now with the advice from several other articles (http://umerpasha.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/c-code-to-get-latest-tweets-using-twitter-api-1-1/), but they all deal with tokens in a different way, none of which have worked up to now. I should possibly have put my energy into investigating why they're not working for me (seem to be working for everyone else) but I don't wish to waste time when your alternative does the job first time without any probs.

Comment: Thanks for this, nice and easy to follow :)

Comment: @StephenGarside No problem. :)

Comment: Hey How can I use it to post a tweet ? I'm doing something like this string status = "Test tweet";
            string tweetUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status="+status;
            HttpWebRequest tweetRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tweetUrl);
            var tweetHeaderFormat = "{0} {1}";
            tweetRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format(tweetHeaderFormat, twitAuthResponse.token_type, twitAuthResponse.access_token));
            tweetRequest.Method = "POST";
            WebResponse tweetResponse = tweetRequest.GetResponse();

Comment: @sohaibjaved Hi, sorry I've not posted a one, I'd have to check myself.

Comment: The "JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();" doesn't really do anything. Maybe you can take that one out for the sake of clarity?

Answer (score 1):

Created a JS only solution to get Twitter posts on your site without using new API - can now specify number of tweets too: http://goo.gl/JinwJ