# Twitter and YouTube Analytics API

Tags: api, twitter

When we login to analytics.twitter.com via our account we could see a brief explanation about our followers like interests and occupation etc.

I have a basic portal that users could logIn via their Twitter accounts and I was wondering that, Is it possible to retrieve those data who loggedIn to my portal via using API?

Those data gathered all under audience insight, and I would like to make a meaningful inference about the people who loggedIn to my portal related the quality of their audience and etc.

All in all, I only would like to know is it possible to retrieve those data via using APIs both for Twitter and Youtube?

Comment: This very simple however , that is if you know what you are doing. Start from here https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: @ShapCyber  I think it lies under ads api here it is https://dev.twitter.com/ads/campaigns/audience-insights

Comment: You solution is simple but wider in scope to be display here. If you want to retrieve all data from any social media account i can help you out.  Contact Me

Answer (score 0):

There is no API available (from Twitter) that provides access to the data values on analytics.twitter.com.

Comment: found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608992/twitter-analytics-data-via-stream-api-using-oauth-access-token