# How to search for tweets using twitter API 1.1 and java

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Twitter API has been changed from 1.0 to 1.1. Now for any type of query it has to be authorized. I am using java for fetching tweets. Can anyone give me some java example of tweet fetching using OAuth authentication.

### Update

Using twitter4j api it is possible. http://twitter4j.org/en/. An example is given below

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken("Your-Access-Token", "Your-Access-Token-Secret");
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("Consumer-Key", "Consumer-Key-Secret");
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

    try {
        Query query = new Query("#IPL");
        QueryResult result;
        result = twitter.search(query);
        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        for (Status tweet : tweets) {
            System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
        }
    }
    catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

### Problems here

This example works independently when I ran as a Java class. But when I add this code in a JSP for testing in webapp it does not work. It shows me following exception

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/mypub] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set.] with root cause
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set.
        at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterBaseImpl.java:264)
        at com.me.framework.tag.core.TweetFetch.doTag(TweetFetch.java:50)
        at org.apache.jsp.template.test_jsp._jspx_meth_wf_002dcore_005ftweetFetch_005f0(test_jsp.java:100)
        at org.apache.jsp.template.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:74)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
```

Comment: I just did the same thing yesterday but using C#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/17071447#17071447

Comment: For java there is a library called twitter4j. It can be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the consumer secret and token multiple times, as indicated by the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set.

It's happening because [`TwitterFactory.getInstance()`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterFactory.html#getInstance%28%29) is returning a singleton of `Twitter`, this is then having `setOAuthConsumer` and `setOAuthAccessToken` invoked on it each time a request is made to your Servlet.

You need to ensure you only configure your `Twitter` instance once and not each time a request is made.

One way of achieving this is by asking the `TwitterFactory` to give you an authenticated instance of `Twitter` by using [`TwitterFactory.getInstance(AccessToken)`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterFactory.html#getInstance%28twitter4j.auth.AccessToken%29):

```
final AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken("Your-Access-Token", "Your-Access-Token-Secret");
final Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getInstance(token);
...
```

An added benefit of this factory method is that it may return a cached, authenticated, instance of `Twitter` for you.

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the codebird js library for tweet search. All you need is to create an app on Twitter and note down the following:

1. Consumer Key
2. Consumer Secret Key
3. Access Token
4. Access Token Secret

Download codebird js Library from the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-js):

Usage:

```
var cb = new Codebird;
cb.setConsumerKey('YOURKEY', 'YOURSECRET');
cb.setToken('YOURTOKEN', 'YOURTOKENSECRET');

cb.__call(
    'oauth2_token',
    {},
    function (reply) {
        var bearer_token = reply.access_token;
    }
);

cb.__call(
    'search_tweets',
    {
        q : "your query which you want to search",
        from : twitter_user
     },
     function (data) 
     {
         console.log(data);
     },
     true // this parameter required
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want it in java. Problem on client side is that my tokens' are visible to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/114/entry-4459-demo-of-twitter-application-only-oauth-authentication-using-java/) to search for tweets using twitter api 1.1 with OAuth Authentication

I have modified the code for my usability and it does not use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html), which is good at the moment because OAuth search is not available in the [RC build](https://twitter.com/t4j_news/status/269812610738814976) (I read it somewhere unable to find the location at the moment)

Also added getting twitter timeline

Code is in [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/)

```
TweetsHelper tweetsHelper = new TweetsHelper()
def bearerToken=tweetsHelper.requestBearerToken(TWITTER_AUTH_URL)
List<TweetsInfo> tweets=tweetsHelper.fetchTimelineTweet(bearerToken)

    private final def TWITTER_HOST = "api.twitter.com"
private final def TWITTER_AUTH_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"
private final def TWITTER_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=INFAsupport&count=200" 
private HttpsURLConnection getHTTPSConnection(String method,String endpointUrl){
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null        
    URL url = new URL(endpointUrl)
    connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection()
    connection.setDoOutput(true)
    connection.setDoInput(true)
    connection.setRequestMethod(method)
    connection.setRequestProperty("Host", TWITTER_HOST)
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", TWITTER_HANDLE)
    connection.setUseCaches(false)
    return connection       
}

//Fetch Bearertoken for getting tweets
public String requestBearerToken(String endPointUrl) throws IOException {

    String encodedCredentials = encodeKeys()
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null
    try {
        connection = getHTTPSConnection("POST",endPointUrl)
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials)
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "29")
        connection.setUseCaches(false)
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid endpoint URL specified.", e)
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect()
        }
    }       

    writeRequest(connection, "grant_type=client_credentials")

    JsonSlurper js=new JsonSlurper()
    def result=js.parseText(readResponse(connection))
    String tokenType = result?.token_type
    String token = result?.access_token

    return ((tokenType.equals("bearer")) && (token != null)) ? token : ""

}

//Search tweets
public List<TweetsInfo> fetchQueriedTweets(def bearerToken) throws IOException {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null
    def dataCleanser = new DataCleanser()
    try {
        connection = getHTTPSConnection("GET",TWITTER_URL)
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken)
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid endpoint URL specified.", e)
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect()
        }
    }

    List<TweetsInfo> tweets= new ArrayList<TweetsInfo>()
    try{
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(readResponse(connection))
        JSONArray objArray = (JSONArray)obj.get(TWEET_STATUSES)

        if (objArray != null) {
            for(int i=0;i<objArray.length();i++){
                String text = dataCleanser.escapeQuotes(((JSONObject)objArray.get(i)).get(TWEET_TEXT).toString())
                String createdAt = DateUtils.convertToUTC(parseTweetDate(((JSONObject)objArray.get(i)).get(TWEET_CREATED_AT).toString()))
                String fromUser = ((JSONObject)objArray.get(i)).get(TWEET_USER).get(TWEET_NAME).toString()
                String expandedURL = ((JSONObject)objArray.get(i)).get(TWEET_ENTITIES).get(TWEET_URLS).get(0).get(TWEET_EXPANDED_URL).toString()
                TweetsInfo tweet=new TweetsInfo(text,fromUser,expandedURL,createdAt)
                tweets.push(tweet)                  
            }   
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        log.info "Exception in TweetsHelper $e"
    }       
    return tweets
}

//Fetch Twitter timeline
public List<TweetsInfo> fetchTimelineTweet(def bearerToken) throws IOException {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null
    List<TweetsInfo> tweets= new ArrayList<TweetsInfo>()
    def dataCleanser = new DataCleanser()
    try {
        connection = getHTTPSConnection("GET",TWITTER_URL)      
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken)
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IOException("Invalid endpoint URL specified.", e)
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect()
        }
    }

    JsonSlurper js=new JsonSlurper()
    try{
        def result=js.parseText(readResponse(connection))
        result?.each{tweet->            
            String text = tweet?.text
            String createdAt = DateUtils.convertToUTC(parseTweetDate(tweet?.created_at))
            String fromUser = tweet?.user?.name
            String expandedURL = tweet?.entities?.urls[0]?.expanded_url
            if(validTweetForAWeek(createdAt)){
                TweetsInfo tweetinfo=new TweetsInfo(text,fromUser,expandedURL,createdAt)
                tweets.push(tweetinfo)
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        log.info "Exception in TweetsHelper $e"
    }
    return tweets       
}
```

`TweetsInfo` is a Pojo class with `String text, String fromUser,    String expandedURL, String createdAt` (this was my requirement)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know.