# Need simple Twitter API v1.1 example to show timeline using jQuery or C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter

With Twitter turning off the API 1.0 faucet on 6/11/2013, we have several sites that now fail to display timelines.  I've been looking for an "If you did that, now do this" example.  Here was Twitter's announcement.
https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

Here is what we were originally doing to show the Twitter timeline via API 1.0.

```
<div id="twitter">
    <ul id="twitter_update_list"></ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/companytwitterhandle.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=1"></script>
    <div style="float:left;"><a href="https://twitter.com/companytwitterhandle" target="_blank">@companytwitterhandle</a> | </div>
    <div class="twitterimg">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Initially I tried changing the version in the JavaScript reference URL like so, which did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline/companytwitterhandle.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=1"></script>
```

Then I looked at the Twitter API documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview) which lacks a clear transition example.  I don't have 4 or 5 hours to delve into that, or into this disheveled FAQ (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#17750).

Then I found this API documentation regarding the user timeline. So I changed the URL again as shown below.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=companytwitterhandle&amp;count=1"></script>
```

That did not work.

Using jQuery or C# ASP.NET MVC, how can I transition that interface from Twitter API 1.0 to Twitter API 1.1?  My first preference would be for a browser client side implementation if that is possible.  Please include a code example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I received an answer from a colleague who had to make a similar change at my company.  Here is the coded solution. He received this from a company we contracted to build a new interface for us with a Twitter timeline.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/companytwitterhandle" data-widget-id="18DigitMagicNumber" data-chrome="nofooter transparent noscrollbar noheader noborders"  data-tweet-limit="1" >Tweets by @@companytwitterhandle</a>
<script>!function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https'; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
```

You will see in the `data-widget-id` attribute `18DigitMagicNumber`. That number is apparently tied to our Twitter handle or our company.  I don't know how that gets generated.

As indicated, a contracted company wrote that code for us, so I won't try to explain what it's all doing.

I cut and pasted this from one site into an unrelated site and it worked immediately.  The only thing I changed was to remove the actual company handle and `data-widget-id`, and to replace the single `@` with `@@` to escape it in MVC.

Hopefully this will help some of you who are also migrating to Twitter 1.1.  Thanks.

Comment: This uses pure JavaScript rather than jQuery as the OP requested, and does not appear to work. https://jsfiddle.net/3xsjn59u/

Comment: @WesModes, I was the OP, and this code worked at the time. The post is nearly 3 years old now, so it may be out of date at this time. No sense in downvoting this though. :)

Comment: Also of note, the fiddle example has the string "18digitmagicnumber" assigned to the data-widget-id, rather than a real Twitter number.  You'd need a real account number for Twitter for that code sample to work.  When at that previous employer, I didn't feel it was prudent to publish that info.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did this:

Please see my question and answer here:

> [Authenticate and request a user's timeline with Twitter API 1.1 oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth)

Use the above solution and render the `json` back to the page, store it in a variable called `json`.

Put a reference to `jQuery` and the twitter-text js library;

> https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js

Add a `div` with an `id` or results to your aspx:

```
 <div id="results"></div>
```

You can render the content with the following javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                $("#results").append('<div class="tweet"><p><span><strong> - ' + json[i].created_at.substring(0, 16) + '</span></strong></span><br/>' + twttr.txt.autoLink(json[i].text) + '</p>');
                try {
                    for (var j = 0; j < json[i].entities.media.length; j++) {
                        $("#results").append('<a href="' + json[i].entities.media[j].media_url + '"><img src="' + json[i].entities.media[j].media_url + ':thumb" /></a>');
                    }

                } catch(e) {
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a `JavaScript` only solution that just works out the box to get `Twitter` posts on your site without using new API - styling is left up to you - can now specify number of tweets too:

> http://goo.gl/JinwJ