# Twitter api V1.1 - getting "(401) Unauthorized" when trying to get user_timeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth, unauthorized

I am trying to get the user timeline from twitter api v1.1 with ASP.NET and it is working fine unless i add the count parameter. My code is below;

```
string oauth_token = "xxx";
    string oauth_token_secret = "xxx";
    string oauth_consumer_key = "xxx";
    string oauth_consumer_secret = "xxx";

    public string GetUserTimeline(string userName, int tweetCount)
    {
        // oauth implementation details
        var oauth_version = "1.0";
        var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

        // unique request details
        var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
            - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        // message api details
        var status = "Updating status via REST API if this works";
        var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
        // create oauth signature
        var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                        "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&screen_name={6}";

        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                    oauth_consumer_key,
                                    oauth_nonce,
                                    oauth_signature_method,
                                    oauth_timestamp,
                                    oauth_token,
                                    oauth_version,
                                     Uri.EscapeDataString(userName)
                                    );

        baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

        string oauth_signature;
        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        // create the request header
        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                        );


        // make the request

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        var postBody = "screen_name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(userName);//
        resource_url += "?" + postBody;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseData.ToString();
    }
```

The problem is when i add the count parameter to limit the number of tweets, i am getting  "(401) Unauthorized" error. Below is the version with parameters;

```
var baseFormat = "count=25&oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                       "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&screen_name={6}";
var postBody = "count=25&screen_name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(userName);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this? It has a link to a GitHub project I created that has exmples in c# asp .net and MVC, might be of some use for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/17071447#17071447

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a typo for the posted question, but you need a & after count=25. Instead of count=25oauth_consumer_key, you should have count=25&oauth_consumer_key.

Comment: Sorry thats my bad but unfortunately this is not the problem.