# Twitter API 1.1 OAuth Status User Time

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, twitter

I am trying to read twitter status into my Windows application which happened to work initially but stopped working after twitter upgraded OAuth to 1.1. It's frustrating me because I am trying to make it work for a week but I haven't been able to solve it. Right now, I am getting the error "Remote server not found: 410 Gone". For reference, here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var oauth_consumer_key = "<Consumer Key>";
        var oauth_consumer_secret = "<Consumer Secret>";
        var oauth_token = "<Access Token>";
        var oauth_token_secret = "<Access Token Secret>";


        try
        {
            //oauth implementation details
            var oauth_version = "1.0";
            var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

            //unique request details
            var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
            var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

            //messsage api details
            //var status = "Updating status via REST API if this works";
            var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

            var screen_name = "cornerstorepos";
            var count = "2";

            //create oauth signature 
            var baseFormat = "count={7}&oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" + 
                             "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&screen_name={6}";
            var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,                                                
                                            oauth_consumer_key, 
                                            oauth_nonce, 
                                            oauth_signature_method, 
                                            oauth_timestamp, 
                                            oauth_token, 
                                            oauth_version,
                                            screen_name,
                                            count
                                            );

            baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url),"&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

            var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),"&",Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

            string oauth_signature;
            using(HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
            {
                oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString))); 
            }

            //create request header
            var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\", oauth_nonce=\"{1}\", oauth_signature=\"{2}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{3}\"," +
                                " oauth_timestamp=\"{4}\", oauth_token=\"{5}\", oauth_version=\"{6}\"";


            var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat, 
                                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key), 
                                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce), 
                                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature), 
                                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method), 
                                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version));

            //make request
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            //var postBody1 = "screen_name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name);
            //var postBody2 = "count=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(count);

            //resource_url += "?" + postBody1 + "&" + postBody2;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization",authHeader);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();


            string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(responseData, LoadOptions.None);
            var query = from ex in document.Root.Descendants("status")
                        select new UserStatus
                        {
                            Status = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ex.Element("text").Value),
                        };
            users = (from u in query.Take(10) where u.Status != "" select u).ToList();

            timer.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

It would be great help if anyone help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The 410 Gone is intended as a response to endpoints belonging to Twitter API v1.0. However, your resource_url appears to be correct. You might want to use Fiddler to watch your HTTP stream to see if any other part of your code is making a request to a deprecated endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

[Authenticate and request a user's timeline with Twitter API 1.1 oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/17071447#17071447)

I have created a GitHub project for this with working examples at:

https://github.com/andyhutch77/oAuthTwitterWrapper