# Twitter api doesnt return timeline

Tags: .net, twitter

not long ago twitter stopped supporting rest 1.0 and I had to find some suloutions using new OAuth system. I found **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/17071447#17071447).**

That worked well and was simple in use. But recently I faced some strange behavior. This, lets call it module, didn't recieved any tweets from given screen name. It passed authentication, but json result was empty, although timeline wasn't empty on twitter.

Did anyone faced such problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented my Twitter client using Twitter 4j Library, Twitter 4j Library is very easy to use.
There are many examples for using Twitter 4j library: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Along with that, You will not have to implement a separate OAuth wrapper while using Twitter 4j and it is also updated to the latest Twitter REST Api 1.1.

Comment: Nice one, but it is on Java, I need .Net version.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the host url from "https://api.twitter.com/1/" to "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/". I think that will solve your problem.

I've done this in twitteroauth library in php.