# Twitter Integration with OAuth with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have been trying to establishing an integration with twitter, what i need is just below features.

1. I should be able to extract all the tweets for my account and display it in my application.
2. I should be able to post status when i enter a text in my textbox and click on submit.

I have tried multiple ways, even used 3rd party Libraries like TweetSharp(it worked pretty well.) As i need to deliver this to a client, i dont want to use any third party tools, as there will be no one to support in case of any issues.

First think it should be completely free. So i have tried using OAuth as explained in the below link. i have updated the twitter api version to 1.1 and added my Consumer Key, Secret, AccessToken and Secret. I executed the application. To my surprise, my message was posted on to the twitter. but when i changed the status and executed again, it stopped working and it keep gives my **un authorized** error.

The example i m following might not be the complete one, may be i need to regenerate a access key and do something else. I m confused. can you please help me how i can proceed further and with link to any post with complete code.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net

Thank you.

Comment: take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth

Answer (score 0):

Every status must be unique, or you'll receive an error. For this reason, I append the date/time to the end of the tweet when testing.

BTW, if you ever change your mind about 3rd party libraries, check out [LINQ to Twitter](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

**Just for Info:**
New API is more strict while sending headers and creating Signature.

Make sure you fulfill these requirements:

Header values should be in sorted order(lexicographically)

GET Request:
Header should **not include** any querystring values.
Signature base should contain all values including querystring values

POST Reqeust:
Header should **include** post parameter values.
Signature base should contain all values including parameter values 
**Post request Url should append all prameter values in QueryString and requst should be sent to that**

This should solve most authorization issues.