# Twitter API Integration - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, twitter

I have tried to integrate twitter API Integration but no luck there is getting  error

> "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. "

Could you please help me as soon as possible?

My Twitter Application details below

```
Access level    Read-only 
About the application permission model

Consumer key    <Consumer Key>
Consumer secret <Consumer Secret>
Request token URL   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
Authorize URL   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
Access token URL    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
Callback URL    http://www.opalevents.org/register
Sign in with Twitter    Yes
```

My Code below

```
![/ oauth application keys
            var oauth_token = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
            var oauth_token_secret = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
            var oauth_consumer_key = "<Consumer Key>";
            var oauth_consumer_secret = "<Consumer Secret>";

            // oauth implementation details
            var oauth_version = "1.0";
            var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

            // unique request details
            var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
                new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
            var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
                - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

            // message api details
            var status = "Updating status via REST API if this works";
            var resource_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json";

            // create oauth signature
            var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                            "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&status={6}";

            var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                        oauth_consumer_key,
                                        oauth_nonce,
                                        oauth_signature_method,
                                        oauth_timestamp,
                                        oauth_token,
                                        oauth_version,
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(status)
                                        );

            baseString = string.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

            var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                    "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

            string oauth_signature;
            using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
            {
                oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                    hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
            }

            // create the request header
            var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                               "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                               "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                               "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

            var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                    Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                            );


            // make the request
            var postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(status);

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte\[\] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
                stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();][1]
```

Comment: Hi, please see my question and answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/17071447#17071447

If you find them of use please upvote.

Comment: You might want to replace your consumer key and secret with dummy values

Comment: hey @Soner Gönül,hutchonoid, I need to tweet from my application how to do it? My requirement is when i click twitter icon from my application then show tweets popup then we can send it like a facebook wall posting.

Comment: I have just faced a similar problem to this but solved it in a different way in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth I created a GitHub project at https://github.com/andyhutch77/oAuthTwitterTimeline

Answer (score 1):

First, your resource url is wrong, it should be: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json

Notice that there is a new version 1.1 .
You can also try to go to the OAuth tool tab and regenerate a new request like this:

[image: OAuth token]

From time to time I have to regenerate my credentials because it kicks me out