# OAuth With Twitter On C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, twitter, twitter-oauth

Simply put, I'm trying to create a webpage with Visual Studio 2012 wherein the user will log into a page, which, when authorized, will post a tweet, and enable them to use the rest of the features on the page. I'd like to remember said users credentials to also limit the rate at which they use a certain feature.

The problem is, I have been searching for days and I am unable to find an UP TO DATE and working example for me to follow. Everything seems to be outdated. (`Twitterizer` ; `TweetSharp`)  I've switched from Java to C# & .NET and still no progress.

I am now seeking direct help.. Code snippets .. Tutorials .. Anything .. So that I can accomplish this task. I'm new to .NET but used to Java & C/C++ so I don't expect to be confused by too trivial of code..

My exact request is to be able to log in with twitter, save credentials (or the user's access token, whatever) & post a tweet.

Comment: LINQ to Twitter isn't outdated: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Comment: @L.B What is your purpose ?

Comment: @JoeMayo I realize. But I'm still having trouble implementing the code.

Comment: @theonlyross There are samples in the downloadable source code - look at the projects titled with the 'Linq2TwitterDemos_' prefix.

Comment: I tried them, but to no avail. [This website](http://umerpasha.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/c-code-to-get-latest-tweets-using-twitter-api-1-1/) is eventually what got me to what I wanted. Well, halfway, really, because I was only able to authenticate & sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the assisting of other persons who have fallen into the same gap I did... Check out [this site](http://umerpasha.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/c-code-to-get-latest-tweets-using-twitter-api-1-1/)

It will help with authenticating & signing in & retrieving basic information.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of how to authenticate and retrieve a user's timeline:

```
// You need to set your own keys and screen name
var oAuthConsumerKey = "superSecretKey";
var oAuthConsumerSecret = "superSecretSecret";
var oAuthUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
var screenname = "aScreenName";

// Do the Authenticate
var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

var authHeader = string.Format(authHeaderFormat,
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey) + ":" +
    Uri.EscapeDataString((oAuthConsumerSecret)))
));

var postBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";

HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);
authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
authRequest.Method = "POST";
authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

using (Stream stream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
    stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
}

authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

WebResponse authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
// deserialize into an object
TwitAuthenticateResponse twitAuthResponse;
using (authResponse)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(authResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var objectText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        twitAuthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitAuthenticateResponse>(objectText);
    }
}

// Do the timeline
var timelineFormat = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={0}&include_rts=1&exclude_replies=1&count=5";
var timelineUrl = string.Format(timelineFormat, screenname);
HttpWebRequest timeLineRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(timelineUrl);
var timelineHeaderFormat = "{0} {1}";
timeLineRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format(timelineHeaderFormat, twitAuthResponse.token_type, twitAuthResponse.access_token));
timeLineRequest.Method = "Get";
WebResponse timeLineResponse = timeLineRequest.GetResponse();
var timeLineJson = string.Empty;
using (timeLineResponse)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(timeLineResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
         timeLineJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}


public class TwitAuthenticateResponse {
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
}
```

Please see here (The github project has asp.net and asp.net mvc examples):

[Authenticate and request a user's timeline with Twitter API 1.1 oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/17071447#17071447)

I created an an open source project for it but unfortunately it doesn't yet include the ability to send tweets. I don't think it would be difficult but I am short on time at the moment.

If I was to implement it I would find out exactly what needs to be posted by the api, as detailed here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

Comment: All this goes into the `PageLoad()` Function ? Remember I'm new to C# & ASP .NET ...

Comment: I would wrap it in a function or use the nuget install from the link to the other question. If you are new to asp .net it might be tricky for you to implement the posting.

Comment: It is .. I'm trying something I found on [this website](http://umerpasha.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/c-code-to-get-latest-tweets-using-twitter-api-1-1/)

Comment: So, this is an old answer, but in case someone else finds this: This answer only works for [Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only). The important part of this is that it CANNOT tweet for someone. To tweet for someone, you have to use the other (more complicated) answer.