# How to pull public tweets from twitter based upon a keyword in C# windows application

Tags: c#, json, winforms, twitter, twitter-oauth

i'am new to .NET and this is my first post,

i would like to know how to pull & display public tweets based on a keyword using C#. I would also like to also get the geolocation of the tweets. I don't need the time line of a particulate user i need public tweets.

I have already created Consumer & Token Key & Secret.

Please remember that i need to implement it in C# Windows Application. It would be great full if some one can guide me. I found another post [OAuth With Twitter On C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783615/oauth-with-twitter-on-c-sharp-net?lq=1) , but this is to pull the timeline can any modification be made to this to serve my purpose

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at: [Net::Twitter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Twitter) module. The documentation for that seems good.

Comment: Thanks for that, but the library is perl . But i need a C# documentation or sample code.