# How to get twitter access token using C# api 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I'm using Twitter sign in api 1.1 and I cannot use any third party for many reasons, my problem is after getting oauth_token and oauth_verifier from the query string I cannot exchange them with an access token so please is there any one have sample code for this section?

Comment: This might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not Implementing Sign in with Twitter.

Comment: Yes it is, if by sign in you mean authentication, it has to happen to retrieve a timeline.

Comment: thanks hutchonoid for your help it works, now my problem is verifying credentials. the request returns (401) oauth unauthorized from twitter.

Comment: Usually the only thing that can go wrong is if you supply invalid details. I would double check them against your twitter account.

Comment: I still cannot verify credentials, is there any other way to get the user profile or data.