# Build twitter feed dynamically on the server then pass to view

Tags: c#, twitter, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-oauth

I've been following this question to retrieve the twitter feed for a particular user [Authenticate and request users timeline twitter api 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth) which is working as expected, the issue I now have is trying to style it to make it look like the twitter feed, the reason we are doing this on the server is because we have a database with all our tweets in so instead of making calls to twitter we have decided to call our database and pull them through.  This was implemented and followed through just encase twitter decided to update there API which may result in our feed working (management didn't want to take that chance.)

I have spent some time today trying to find a possible solution to see if this has been done already, I'm aware people have provided server side code to retrieve the tweets but I can't find an example of passing the tweets to the view and displaying them.

Comment: Do you have a question of some sort or are you just updating us on how you're doing?

Comment: @RonBeyer apologies on not being clear, I'm trying to pass the feed which has been called server side to the client side and have it display i.e look and feel as the twitter feed shown on twitter it self but I can't seem to find if any a good tutorial/solution on doing so.  Do you know of such solution?

Comment: What is the problem in here? You will get tweets as json array, which you can process to extract fields and save in your table. While sending the tweets to a view you just have to bind them to a view model. Having, said that I consider saving tweets in a database is a waste of time and effort. Tweets have a very small lifespan and they are anyways saved in the Twitter account.