# Twiiter API Access Rights

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

Just for fun last night I started to write a Twitter App, basic stuff it would search for tweets, follow some people, RT and Favourite tweets containing certain words etc.

I used this example for getting started 
[Stack OverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth)

I modified it to search for what I wanted and great I had a list of tweets, I was thinking I'm s@#t hot. Then I wrote a whole bunch of code to RT and Follow some people and every "POST" request I made fell down with the following error.

> {"errors":[{"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this
>   resource","code":220}]}

After some research I only appear to have Application-only authentication..
My question is how do I get authentication to make "POST" Requests?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I asked the question because I don't fully understand the process on dev.twitter.com, I thought I had implemented what I needed to "Post" but I was incorrect